# How create environment variable for tomcat?

Tags: environment-variables, tomcat8

I'm trying create environment variable in tomcat 8 for my project, I need use this variable for choice properties logger. I read about `setenv.sh` and i create this file, but when i run my project  - it does not run. How me create environment variable for  check my project?
I read about `setenv` in this [site](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/v4.3/tds/tds4.2/tutorial/GettingStarted.html). I use ubuntu 14.04.

**setenv.sh**

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
export JAVA_HOME

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -Xms512m -server"
export JAVA_OPTS

CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat"
export CATALINA_HOME
```

Comment: Have you made the file executable?

Comment: @JoachimRohde, I made `setenv.sh`, this is executable file?

Comment: @JoachimRohde, i set chechout in properties file: `Execute: Allow executing file as program `

Answer (score 12):

Please do the following. It'll work for you.

```
   1 sudo su and cd to /var/lib/tomcat8/bin/
   2 touch setenv.sh(if it doesn't exist)
   3 chmod 777 setenv.sh
   4 vim setenv.sh and set following line in setenv.sh
       export varriable=value
   5 sudo service tomcat8 restart
```

and Enjoy...!!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than create `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh`, you can put those settings in `/etc/default/tomcat8`.

I've found that setting JAVA_HOME in *setenv.sh* causes tomcat8 to not start up properly if it doesn't match what `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` comes up with.   The *init.d* script ignores *setenv.sh* but needs to know which java version is used so that it can check the process list to see if tomcat is running.   The *init.d* script does use `/etc/default/tomcat8`, so it makes sense to delete *setenv.sh* and just put the settings in `/etc/default`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternate way if we're using eclipse:

1. Go to `Servers` tab
2. Double click on the server
3. Click `Open launch configuration`
4. Go to `Environment` tab
5. Click `New` and set the key-value pair of environment variables